# Return first table data regardless if second table returns data, operator join normalization

Tags: mysql, normalization

I have two MySQL tables, 'sections' and 'pages'.

I'm trying to us a single query to fetch the data from one or both tables.

If the section and page exists the AND operator works fine.

If the section and page do not exist then the AND operator is fine as well.

However I can not seem to find a way to pull from the section table if the page does not exist (AND operator issue) in conjunction with index.php urls (pulls all the index.php pages for the site).

I'm trying to write better queries so here are my goals and what I have tried:

I do not want to pull all the pages that match the section and then iterate through them.

I do not want to waste resources on executing a second query if this can be done in a single query.

I currently have two if conditioned queries (only one will execute for a given page load) as pages with 'index.php' URL will pull for all sections.

I have used FROM in conjunction with the sections table though I have also tried LEFT JOIN on the page table as well.

This works for pages that aren't indexes:

```
(SELECT NULL AS meta_description FROM sections WHERE url = 'example')
UNION
(SELECT meta_description FROM pages WHERE url = 'something');
```

That query returns up to two rows and is easy enough to work with.

---

Section and page exists, returns result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sections AS cs 
LEFT JOIN pages AS cp ON (cp.id_section = cs.id) 
WHERE cs.section_url LIKE BINARY 'section_url' AND cp.url LIKE BINARY 'index.php'
```

---

Section exists, page does not, returns 0 rows...

```
SELECT * 
FROM sections AS cs 
LEFT JOIN pages AS cp ON (cp.id_section = cs.id) 
WHERE cs.section_url LIKE BINARY 'section_url' AND cp.url LIKE BINARY 'not_exist'
```

---

Table structure:

**pages**: id, section_id, meta_description, meta_language, meta_robots, title, url

**sections**: id, section_id, meta_description, meta_language, meta_robots, title, url

Most importantly I want to ensure that the syntax is SQL neutral as I plan to eventually migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can you post the query you have with AND that doesn't work?

Comment: I'm very confused. Some things that might help clarify what you're asking: (1) posting the table definitions; (2) posting the queries that you mention that use `AND`; (3) posting the queries that you mention that use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Okay working on editing the post...

Comment: Added table structure and other query with example of it working and not (returns 0 rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly guessing, as I'm not sure what **exactly** you want to achieve, but try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sections AS cs 
LEFT JOIN pages AS cp ON (cp.id_section = cs.id AND cp.url LIKE BINARY 'not exists') 
WHERE cs.section_url LIKE BINARY 'section_url'
```

Comment: Initially seems good, just need to figure out something with my table structure though I think this may turn out to be the answer; working on it...

Comment: Ok, good luck. :-) Just keep in mind that if you have more than one page with a given id_section, you will get multiple rows for that one section (each row with a different page). But that can't be helped in case of join.

Comment: Accepted and up-voted. I haven't seen example examples of more than one row being returned (e.g. index.php) since only one page url (e.g. index.php) would JOIN to a given section and no page can JOIN to multiple sections.